# Destroying buttons in a memory game- Python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm working on a memory game in Python Tkinter and I'm trying to destroy cards whenever there is a match. Like when two cards are flipped and are matching, they need to be destroyed. The cards are made from buttons. The check function in my code checks whether there's a match and destroys the cards if so. The problem is it's not doing it. Can someone please help me do it?
My code:

```
from tkinter import *
from random import shuffle
from tkinter import messagebox

screen = Tk()
screen.title("Disney Princesses Memory Game")
width = screen.winfo_screenwidth()
height = screen.winfo_screenheight()
screen.geometry("%dx%d" % (width, height))
screen.configure(bg="#e0bce5")

title = Label(screen, text="Memory Game", font=("David", 50, "underline", "bold"), bg="#e0bce5")
title.place(x=400, y=20)
rules = Label(screen, text="Single click to flip the first card, double click to flip the second card",
              font=("David", 30, "bold"), bg="#e0bce5")
rules.place(x=100, y=100)

images_list = [
    PhotoImage(file="images/aurora.png"),
    PhotoImage(file="images/belle.png"),
    PhotoImage(file="images/cinderella.png"),
    PhotoImage(file="images/jasmine.png"),
    PhotoImage(file="images/mulan.png"),
    PhotoImage(file="images/rapunzel.png"),
    PhotoImage(file="images/snow white.png"),
    PhotoImage(file="images/tiana.png")
]

buttons_list = []
chosen_images = []
flipped = []
num_list = []
card = PhotoImage(file="images/card.png")
count = 0
no_press = False
turn = 0
player1_points = 0
player2_points = 0


def choose_images():
    while len(chosen_images) < 16:
        duplicate = images_list.copy()
        images_list.extend(duplicate)

        shuffle(images_list)
        for i2 in images_list:
            chosen_images.append(i2)


def turns():
    global turn
    turn += 1

    if turn % 2 == 0:
        turn_label.configure(text="Player 1's turn")
    else:
        turn_label.configure(text="Player 2's turn")


def replace_card(c, d):
    global flipped, count, no_press

    if no_press is True:
        return

    count += 1

    if count > 2:
        count = 0
        no_press = True
        check()
    else:
        buttons_list[c][d].configure(image=chosen_images[(c*7)+d])
        flipped.append(buttons_list[c][d])


def reset():
    global card, no_press
    for element in flipped:
        element.configure(image=card)
    flipped.clear()
    no_press = False
    turns()


def sleep_secs():
    global no_press
    screen.after(2000, reset)


def check():
    global player1_points, player2_points
    if flipped[0] == flipped[1]:
        flipped[0].destroy()
        flipped[1].destroy()
        flipped.clear()
        if turn_label["text"] == "Player 1's turn":
            player1_points += 1
        else:
            player2_points += 1
    else:
        sleep_secs()

    if player1_points + player2_points == 8:
        if player1_points > player2_points:
            messagebox.showinfo("Disney Princesses Memory Game", "Player 1 is the winner!")
        elif player2_points > player1_points:
            messagebox.showinfo("Disney Princesses Memory Game", "Player 2 is the winner!")
        else:
            messagebox.showinfo("Disney Princesses Memory Game", "The game ended in a draw!")


choose_images()

turn_label = Label(screen, text="Player 1's turn!", font=("David", 20), fg="red", bg="#e0bce5")
turn_label.place(x=520, y=180)
x = 100
y = 250
for i in range(2):
    buttons_list.append([])
    for j in range(8):
        a = Button(screen, image=card, command=lambda i=i, j=j: replace_card(i, j))
        x += 100
        a.place(x=x, y=y)
        buttons_list[i].append(a)
    y += 100
    x = 100

screen.mainloop()
```

A big thanks to PCM for once again helping me!
Updated code:

```
from tkinter import *
from random import shuffle
from tkinter import messagebox

screen = Tk()
screen.title("Disney Princesses Memory Game")
width = screen.winfo_screenwidth()
height = screen.winfo_screenheight()
screen.geometry("%dx%d" % (width, height))
screen.configure(bg="#e0bce5")

title = Label(screen, text="Memory Game", font=("David", 50, "underline", "bold"), bg="#e0bce5")
title.place(x=400, y=20)
rules = Label(screen, text="Single click to flip the first card, double click to flip the second card",
              font=("David", 30, "bold"), bg="#e0bce5")
rules.place(x=100, y=100)

images_list = [
    PhotoImage(file="images/aurora.png"),
    PhotoImage(file="images/belle.png"),
    PhotoImage(file="images/cinderella.png"),
    PhotoImage(file="images/jasmine.png"),
    PhotoImage(file="images/mulan.png"),
    PhotoImage(file="images/rapunzel.png"),
    PhotoImage(file="images/snow white.png"),
    PhotoImage(file="images/tiana.png")
]

buttons_list = []
chosen_images = []
flipped = []
num_list = []
card = PhotoImage(file="images/card.png")
count = 0
no_press = False
turn = 0
player1_points = 0
player2_points = 0


def choose_images():
    while len(chosen_images) < 16:
        duplicate = images_list.copy()
        images_list.extend(duplicate)

        shuffle(images_list)
        for i2 in images_list:
            chosen_images.append(i2)


def turns():
    global turn
    turn += 1

    if turn % 2 == 0:
        turn_label.configure(text="Player 1's turn")
    else:
        turn_label.configure(text="Player 2's turn")


def replace_card(c, d):
    global flipped, count, no_press
    flipped.append(buttons_list[c][d])

    if no_press is True:
        return

    count += 1

    if count > 2:
        no_press = True
        check()
        count = 0
    else:
        buttons_list[c][d].configure(image=chosen_images[(c * 7) + d])


def reset():
    global card, no_press
    for element in flipped:
        element.configure(image=card)
    flipped.clear()
    no_press = False
    turns()


def sleep_secs():
    global no_press
    screen.after(2000, reset)


def check():
    global player1_points, player2_points

    if flipped[0]["image"] == flipped[1]["image"]:

        flipped[0].destroy()
        flipped[1].destroy()
        flipped.clear()

        if turn_label["text"] == "Player 1's turn":
            player1_points += 1
        else:
            player2_points += 1
    else:
        sleep_secs()

    if player1_points + player2_points == 8:
        if player1_points > player2_points:
            messagebox.showinfo("Disney Princesses Memory Game", "Player 1 is the winner!")
        elif player2_points > player1_points:
            messagebox.showinfo("Disney Princesses Memory Game", "Player 2 is the winner!")
        else:
            messagebox.showinfo("Disney Princesses Memory Game", "The game ended in a draw!")


choose_images()

turn_label = Label(screen, text="Player 1's turn!", font=("David", 20), fg="red", bg="#e0bce5")
turn_label.place(x=520, y=180)
x = 100
y = 250
for i in range(2):
    buttons_list.append([])
    for j in range(8):
        a = Button(screen, image=card, command=lambda i=i, j=j: replace_card(i, j))
        x += 100
        a.place(x=x, y=y)
        buttons_list[i].append(a)
    y += 100
    x = 100

screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: After destroying the object, try calling Tk.update() . I am not at my PC at the moment to give it a test, but it might solve your issue. Let me know how that goes.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. The cards just flip back

Comment: Hmm, let me take a look deeper then. give me a few.

Comment: The thing is your function is never getting called because count is always going to be less than 2

Comment: the check function is getting called in the replace_card function

Comment: Your replace card only runs if the count >2, in other words, if the count is three or higher. And I assume you need it to be 2 or higher (so count > 1?)

Comment: hmmm I'll try that

Comment: But when I type count > 1, it says "list index out of range"

Comment: Hello, in `replace_card` you should add the flipped card to the `flipped` list in all cases, as this will address your "List index out of range" issue when checking count > 1.

Comment: I typed count > 2 because count goes up by 1 before I check anything and if I don't type that, only one card is flipped

Comment: Try printing the flipped list, you will see that the buttons are not the same

Comment: the count > 2 part is correct and that is not part of the issue

Comment: @PCM, ok, I'll try

Comment: Actually, what @PCM said is correct, when you do flipped[0] == flipped[1] it will always be false, since they are not the exact same button. You may want to somehow check if their image is the same?

Comment: @Cooper Harasyn, oh you’re right! I don’t know how I haven’t noticed that. I’ll change it to: if flipped[0][“image”] == flipped[1][“image”]. I think that will work.

Comment: Oh sorry I did not see your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to my comment there are a lot of things to be changed.

The complete code:

```
from tkinter import *
from random import shuffle
from tkinter import messagebox

screen = Tk()
screen.title("Disney Princesses Memory Game")
width = screen.winfo_screenwidth()
height = screen.winfo_screenheight()
screen.geometry("%dx%d" % (width, height))
screen.configure(bg="#e0bce5")

title = Label(screen, text="Memory Game", font=("David", 50, "underline", "bold"), bg="#e0bce5")
title.place(x=400, y=20)
rules = Label(screen, text="Single click to flip the first card, double click to flip the second card",
              font=("David", 30, "bold"), bg="#e0bce5")
rules.place(x=100, y=100)

images_list = [
    PhotoImage(file="images/aurora.png"),
    PhotoImage(file="images/belle.png"),
    PhotoImage(file="images/cinderella.png"),
    PhotoImage(file="images/jasmine.png"),
    PhotoImage(file="images/mulan.png"),
    PhotoImage(file="images/rapunzel.png"),
    PhotoImage(file="images/snow white.png"),
    PhotoImage(file="images/tiana.png")
]

buttons_list = []
chosen_images = []
flipped = []
num_list = []
card = PhotoImage(file="images/card.png")
count = 0
no_press = False
turn = 0
player1_points = 0
player2_points = 0


def choose_images():
    while len(chosen_images) < 16:
        duplicate = images_list.copy()
        images_list.extend(duplicate)

        shuffle(images_list)
        for i2 in images_list:
            chosen_images.append(i2)


def turns():
    global turn
    turn += 1

    if turn % 2 == 0:
        turn_label.configure(text="Player 1's turn")
    else:
        turn_label.configure(text="Player 2's turn")


def replace_card(c, d):
    global flipped, count, no_press
    flipped.append(buttons_list[c][d])
    
    if no_press is True:
        return

    count += 1

    if count > 2:
        no_press = True
        check()
        count = 0
    else:
        buttons_list[c][d].configure(image=chosen_images[(c*7)+d])


def reset():
    global card, no_press
    for element in flipped:
        element.configure(image=card)
    flipped.clear()
    no_press = False
    turns()


def sleep_secs():
    global no_press
    screen.after(2000, reset)


def check():
    global player1_points, player2_points

    if flipped[0]['image'] == flipped[1]['image']:
        
        flipped[0].destroy()
        flipped[1].destroy()
        flipped.clear()
        
        if turn_label["text"] == "Player 1's turn":
            player1_points += 1
        else:
            player2_points += 1
    else:
        sleep_secs()

    if player1_points + player2_points == 8:
        if player1_points > player2_points:
            messagebox.showinfo("Disney Princesses Memory Game", "Player 1 is the winner!")
        elif player2_points > player1_points:
            messagebox.showinfo("Disney Princesses Memory Game", "Player 2 is the winner!")
        else:
            messagebox.showinfo("Disney Princesses Memory Game", "The game ended in a draw!")


choose_images()

turn_label = Label(screen, text="Player 1's turn!", font=("David", 20), fg="red", bg="#e0bce5")
turn_label.place(x=520, y=180)
x = 100
y = 250
for i in range(2):
    buttons_list.append([])
    for j in range(8):
        a = Button(screen, image=card, command=lambda i=i, j=j: replace_card(i, j))
        x += 100
        a.place(x=x, y=y)
        buttons_list[i].append(a)
    y += 100
    x = 100

screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I’ll run the code when I’m in front of my computer

Comment: Please note that I have not added any future parts for the program

Comment: can I get help with one more thing please? If so, occasionally, a card or two are being generated more than twice and another card is generated only once. Do you know what's causing that? If so, please help me

Comment: I do not think so that happens, all are getting generated equally I think

Comment: It happens about every game for some reason which I'm not aware of. There is always one picture that has three cards displaying it and another picture that only has one card displaying it

Comment: buttons_list[c][d].configure(image=chosen_images[(c*7)+d]) should have c*8 instead

Comment: @Cooper Harasyn, thank you so much! I really appreciate it!